# Upgrading to Mac OS Lion

Tags: android

I develop Android apps on a Macbook Pro with Snow Leopard on using Eclipse and am looking to upgrade the laptop to Lion which was released yesterday but am wondering if there will be any problems running Java/Eclipse on this?

Has anyone else upgraded and did they have any issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just upgraded. Haven't encountered any problems / bugs yet. Fell free to upgrade imho.

**Edit:** One thing I've just noticed - the scrollbars changed in eclipse too, and with the new style the markings (that mark the lines in the opened document where problems or warnings appear) seems to have disappeared.